# HTML mobile application and tables

Tags: html, css, mobile

I would like to consult about a solution I'm trying to implement
I need to create a calendar for a mobile web based application (jQuery mobile). I need to create a month view (all days in a single current month).

I found `FullCalendar`, which seems to be a popular and wildly used (and also easy to use and friendly plugin). I consider using it on as my calendar on the web based mobile application.

I started implementing the design on the plugin, but then my manager saw that the design is based on tables and raised fears that tables (as a not very popular HTML element) might cause some compatability problems on some phones. On the other hand, I believe that tables are valid and usful for tabular data (such as a monthly calendar :)

I searched the web but couldn't find any such known or common issues, but would like to ask advise before I put more effort into this solution.

My question - Are you aware of any downsides to using tables in mobile apps? I know that `FullCalendar` is a very popular plugin and seems that no one cares about the tables, but are there any issues someone here is familiar with that could cause any layout display issues due to the use of tables? common devices that have problems using tables / common browser that might misdisplay data/layout?

Thanks and have a great day,
Yaniv

Answer (score 0):

@Yanipan As you said table is for tabular data not for a complete design, that's stuff from the past. Are you using any css framework like **[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)**, **[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)**? If the answer is no, I think you should, with them you can speed up you dev. time 80%. For testing you can use the **[Chrome Mobile emulation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation)**. Good luck!